# ADD INSEET to SELECT QUERY for missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have the following simplified table.

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        month        |     customer     |      value       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        A         |        20        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        B         |        20        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        C         |        20        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        A         |        20        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        B         |        20        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

As you can see, There is not value for customer C, for month 2.

In this instance I need to programtically add month='2' customer='C' value='0', inside my select statement

`SELECT month, customer, value FROM mytable`

I have many more rows in my real table, but the end result needs to be the same customer list for each month.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select m.month, c.customer, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from (select distinct month from t) m cross join
     (select distinct customer from t) c left join
     t
     on t.month = m.month and t.customer = c.customer;
```

Note:  If you have other sources for the months or customers, then those are probably faster than using `count(distinct)`.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the cross join will occur before the left join or does it not matter in this case? Also this assumes there is at least one customer for every month.

Comment: @P.Salmon . . . I'm don't understand your question.  A SQL query *describes* the result set being produced.  It does not specify *how* it is generated.  The optimizer determines what operations are run when.